# iOS App store release issues

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I submitted my application to iTunes yesterday. Till today noon it was showing processing and suddenly now it's showing a red pop up near my build in activity. On clicking it shows a pop up with an error message : ITC.apps.preReleaseBuild.errors.processingFailed. Did anyone came across this issue or resolved it? Is this my build's problem or something related with iTunes connect.

Comment: try with new build version ...

Comment: Please upload new build with update the Build Version in xcode General Tab.

Comment: Looks like everyone is experiencing these issues, based on the activity in the Apple Developer forums, I think we'll just have to wait for Apple to fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately this bug at ITC is out of your control and we have to wait until Apple has fixed it. Anyway it's helping me to know, that I am not the only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Guys the issue was solved automatically. I was able to submit my build  for review without even repeating the upload process.

Answer (score -1):

This is not in your hand, I faced the same problem, the build was showing red badge with itc eroor status.
I did nothing and next day it has been resolve automatically.

There was a problem form apple server end so you don't need to do anything just wait.

Comment: shouldnt build version be int?

Comment: This won't solve this problem. Unfortunately this bug at ITC is out of your control and we have to wait until Apple has fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes it has been resolved it self